# Ubuntu PXE installation is not asking for the hostname or domain

Tags: 14.04, pxe, preseed, hostname

I'm using a PXE server for installing systems in my network. I want it to ask for the hostname and domain on every install instead of asigning 'kickseed' everytime. I cannot figure out what is causing this as I've not specified the name anywhere as far as I can tell and the configuration is only slightly adapter from a working one for Debian Wheezy.
I've already seen the other questions on here that were similar, but none of the solutions seemed to work/apply to my case (e.g. "netcfg/get_hostname=...").

```
kernel ubuntu/14.04_server/amd64/linux
append vga=normal ks=http://10.150.253.2/install/kickstart.ks initrd=ubuntu/14.04_server/amd64/initrd.gz locale=de_DE netcfg/wireless_wep= netcfg/interface=eth0 preseed/url=http://10.150.253.2/install/ubuntu/14.04_server/amd64/ubuntu.seed keymap=de --
```

The seed file:

```
d-i debian-installer/locale string de_DE.UTF-8
d-i debian-installer/language string de
d-i debian-installer/country string DE
d-i debian-installer/locale string de_DE.UTF-8
d-i languagechooser/language-name-fb select German
d-i localechooser/supported-locales en_US.UTF-8
d-i console-setup/ask_detect boolean false
d-i keyboard-configuration/layoutcode string de
d-i console-setup/layoutcode string de

d-i netcfg/choose_interface select auto
d-i netcfg/dhcp_timeout string 60
d-i netcfg/disable_dhcp boolean false
d-i netcfg/wireless_wep string
d-i hw-detect/load_firmware boolean true

d-i mirror/protocol string ftp
d-i mirror/ftp/hostname string <...>
d-i mirror/ftp/directory string /ubuntu
d-i mirror/ftp/proxy string
d-i mirror/ftp/mirror select <...>
d-i mirror/suite string trusty
d-i mirror/udeb/suite string trusty
d-i mirror/udeb/components multiselect main, restricted

d-i clock-setup/utc boolean true
d-i time/zone string Europe/Berlin

d-i partman/default_filesystem string btrfs

d-i base-installer/kernel/image string linux-image-generic-lts-utopic

d-i passwd/root-login boolean true
d-i passwd/make-user boolean false
d-i passwd/root-password-crypted password <...>
d-i user-setup/encrypt-home boolean false

d-i apt-setup/restricted boolean true
d-i apt-setup/universe boolean true
d-i apt-setup/multiverse boolean true
d-i apt-setup/services-select multiselect security
d-i apt-setup/hostname string <...>
d-i apt-setup/directory string /ubuntu
apt-mirror-setup apt-setup/partner boolean true

tasksel tasksel/first multiselect standard

d-i pkgsel/include string \
        openssh-server \
        vim-nox \
        ntp \
        xinetd

d-i pkgsel/language-packs multiselect de, en
d-i pkgsel/update-policy select unattended-upgrades

popularity-contest popularity-contest/participate boolean false

d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean true
d-i grub-installer/with_other_os boolean true

d-i finish-install/reboot_in_progress note

xserver-xorg xserver-xorg/autodetect_monitor boolean true
xserver-xorg xserver-xorg/config/monitor/lcd boolean true
xserver-xorg xserver-xorg/config/monitor/selection-method \
       select medium
xserver-xorg xserver-xorg/config/monitor/mode-list \
       select 1024x768 @ 60 Hz

d-i preseed/late_command string \
        in-target wget http://10.150.253.2/install/ubuntu/14.04_server/amd64/ubuntu_postinst.sh -O /root/postinst.sh; \
        in-target /bin/bash /root/postinst.sh; \
        in-target rm /root/postinst.sh
```